# In which point the tangent of $y= \sin x - \cos x$ is parallel with $y = x$?

Tags: functions, trigonometry, derivatives, tangent-line

Isn't the graph of $y = \sin x - \cos x$ a continous "set of waves". That means that there are several points where the tangent of the function is parallel with $y = x$.
That's how I understand it at least. 
Could someone explain, how exactly can you find this?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to solve $$(\sin{x}-\cos{x})'=1,$$
which is $$\cos{x}+\sin{x}=1$$ or
$$\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4}+x\right)=\frac{1}{\sqrt2}...$$

Comment: So to my understanding:

(cosx + sinx)^2 = 1^2

sin^2 + 2sinxcosx + cos^2 = 1

sin2x = 0

How exactly do we end up in sin(pi/4 + x) = 1/sqrt(2)
Sorry for the trouble, but I am used to different methods when it comes to trigonometry.

Comment: @Teabx You can not do it because you'll obtain also roots of $\sin{x}+\cos{x}=-1$, which you don't need. Solve the last equation in my post. It gives the answer.

Comment: So the final answer is x = 2npi + pi/2?
Thank you for the help :)

Comment: @Teabx The final answer is $2\pi k$ or $\frac{\pi}{2}+2\pi k$, where $k\in\mathbb Z$.

Answer (score 1):

the slope of tangent of a function can be calculated with its derivative$$y_1'=[\sin(x)-\cos(x)]'=\cos(x)+\sin(x)\\y_2'=x'=1$$ 
now just compare them:
$$\cos(x)+\sin(x)=1$$you will get $x=\begin{cases}2\pi n\\2\pi n+{\pi\over2}\end{cases},\,n\in\Bbb Z$

Comment: Hmmm not sure why i ended up with x = 2npi + pi/2. But i think that's the same deal anyway. Thank you for helping.

Comment: @Teabx yea, you are also right, i was pretty dumb and stopped after the first solution

Comment: @Teabx you can easily see that if you switch $\cos(x)$ with $\sqrt{1-\sin^2x}$ and say $u=\sin(x)$(it will gives you the answer $2\pi n,\text{arcsin}(2)$ because the later is out of the new domain you ignore it). i stopped here but i had to also do the same with $\sin(x)=\sqrt{1-\cos^2x}$ which will give you the other solution(you have to be careful with this way because it gives you only the positive solutions, through symmetry you can say it is also negative)